# Can't resolve Java.lang.NullPointerException with ParseObject

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am developing an Android app which uses parse cloud. I am trying to store some values from my database in parse via a List of ParseObjects. Here is the code for my button click action.

```
  Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText Edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            input_email=Edit1.getText().toString();
            if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
                if (checkEmail(input_email)) {


                    ParseObject User = new ParseObject("User");
                    User.put("Email_Id", input_email);
                    User.put("Quote_Value", final_quote);
                    User.saveInBackground();

                    List<ParseObject> Product= new List<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void add(int i, ParseObject parseObject) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean add(ParseObject parseObject) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean addAll(int i, Collection<? extends ParseObject> parseObjects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends ParseObject> parseObjects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void clear() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean contains(Object o) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> objects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean equals(Object o) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public ParseObject get(int i) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int hashCode() {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int indexOf(Object o) {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean isEmpty() {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Iterator<ParseObject> iterator() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public ListIterator<ParseObject> listIterator() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public ListIterator<ParseObject> listIterator(int i) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public ParseObject remove(int i) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean remove(Object o) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> objects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> objects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public ParseObject set(int i, ParseObject parseObject) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int size() {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public List<ParseObject> subList(int i, int i2) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Object[] toArray() {
                            return new Object[0];
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] ts) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    List<Product_database> checked_product_Description = db.getSelectProducts();
                    for (Product_database pd : checked_product_Description) {
                        ParseObject product_data = new ParseObject("products");
                        product_data.put("Product_Description", pd.getProduct_name());
                        product_data.put("Product_Price", pd.getProduct_prices());
                        product_data.put("Product_Quantity", pd.getProduct_quantity());
                        Product.add(product_data);

                    }

                    saveAllInBackground(Product);


                    List<ParseObject> Add_ons= new List<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void add(int i, ParseObject parseObject) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean add(ParseObject parseObject) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean addAll(int i, Collection<? extends ParseObject> parseObjects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends ParseObject> parseObjects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void clear() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean contains(Object o) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> objects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean equals(Object o) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public ParseObject get(int i) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int hashCode() {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int indexOf(Object o) {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean isEmpty() {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Iterator<ParseObject> iterator() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public ListIterator<ParseObject> listIterator() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public ListIterator<ParseObject> listIterator(int i) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public ParseObject remove(int i) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean remove(Object o) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> objects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> objects) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public ParseObject set(int i, ParseObject parseObject) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int size() {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public List<ParseObject> subList(int i, int i2) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Object[] toArray() {
                            return new Object[0];
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] ts) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    List<Add_on_database> checked_Add_ons_Description = add_db.getSelectAdd_ons();

                    for (Add_on_database ad : checked_Add_ons_Description) {
                        ParseObject add_on_data = new ParseObject("add_ons");
                        add_on_data.put("Add_on_Description", ad.getAdd_on_name());
                        add_on_data.put("Add_on_Price", ad.getAdd_on_prices());
                        add_on_data.put("Add_on_Quantity", ad.getAdd_on_quantity());
                        Add_ons.add(add_on_data);

                    }
                    saveAllInBackground(Add_ons);



                }
                 else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a valid Email Id!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Your Network Connection. Application needs active network to send mails!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }});
```

Here is my Logcat from Android Studio:

```
   09-10 04:17:07.462    1266-1266/com.example.chmp.client04 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-10 04:17:16.650    1266-1266/com.example.chmp.client04 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-10 04:17:16.650    1266-1266/com.example.chmp.client04 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4db0b20)
09-10 04:17:16.662    1266-1266/com.example.chmp.client04 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chmp.client04, PID: 1266
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.parse.ParseTraverser.traverseInternal(ParseTraverser.java:85)
            at com.parse.ParseTraverser.traverse(ParseTraverser.java:128)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.collectDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:2188)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.collectDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:2251)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.deepSaveAsync(ParseObject.java:2294)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.saveAllAsync(ParseObject.java:2447)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(ParseObject.java:2646)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(ParseObject.java:2657)
            at com.example.chmp.client04.UI.email_sender$1.onClick(email_sender.java:216)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 04:17:19.482    1266-1266/com.example.chmp.client04 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1266 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding List methods with empty stubs, this does not make sense. Instead use some non abstract List implementation, ArrayList would be a good candidate.

Comment: Thank you. ArrayList does the job.!!